# Processing: no output from code within draw()

Tags: processing

In the following code, it runs without error, but there is no output.  However, when I remove the code from the draw() loop, it outputs successfully.
If I put the code in a for loop, then the output only occurs at the end of the for loop, not during the for loop.
I don't understand why there is no output in both of these cases.

```
void setup(){
  size(800,800);
}

int rows = height;
int cols = width;
int [][] myArray = new int[rows][cols];

void draw(){
  background(255);
  for (int i=0;i<cols;i=i+10){
    for (int j=0;j<rows;j=j+10){
      myArray[i][j]=int(random(255));
    }
  }
  for (int i=0;i<cols;i=i+10){
    for (int j=0;j<rows;j=j+10){
      fill(myArray[i][j]);
      rect(i,j,i+10,j+10);
    } 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`width` and `height` don't have real values until after `size()` is called. Just because you've put the variables after the function, does not mean they get assigned after `setup()` runs: all global variables are assigned *BEFORE* any functions are run. So in this case you end up with a width and height of 0, which will draw absolutely nothing because there are no pixels to color =)

You want this instead:

```
// let's put our global vars up top, to prevent confusion.
// Any global variable that isn't just declared but also
// initialised, gets initialised before *anything* else happens.
int rows, cols;
int[][] myArray;

// Step 2 is that setup() runs
void setup(){
  size(800,800);
  // now we can initialise values:
  rows = width;
  cols = height;
  myArray = new int[rows][cols];
}

// Setup auto-calls draw() once, and
// then draw() runs at a specific framerate
// unless you've issued noLoop() at some point.
void draw(){
  background(255);
  for (int i=0;i<cols;i=i+10){
    for (int j=0;j<rows;j=j+10){
      myArray[i][j]=int(random(255));
    }
  }
  for (int i=0;i<cols;i=i+10){
    for (int j=0;j<rows;j=j+10){
      fill(myArray[i][j]);
      rect(i,j,i+10,j+10);
    }  
  }
}
```

That said, we don't even need `rows` and `cols` here, we can just use `width` and `height` directly, and we don't need two loops, we just need one since we're not using not-yet-set neighbouring pixels when we draw the rectangles. We just need to skip by 10 all the time, which you already do:

```
int[][] myArray;

// Step 2 is that setup() runs
void setup() {
  size(800,800);
  myArray = new int[width][height];
}

void draw() {
  background(255);
  int i, j, step = 10;
  for (i=0; i<height; i=i+step) {
    for (j=0; j<width; j=j+step) {
      myArray[i][j]=int(random(255));
      fill(myArray[i][j]);
      rect(i,j,i+step,j+step);
    }  
  }
}
```